# Command to get SHA384, 256 and SHA512 hashes in AIX servers

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, aix

For AIX servers to get the MD5 and SHA1 hashes, I am able to use the command:

```
csum -h MD5 file1
csum -h SHA1 file1
```

But how to use the same command to get sha256, 384, 512 hashes ?

Or is there some other utility that I can use for getting the information. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As [Lorinczy](https://superuser.com/users/1015128/lorinczy-zsigmond) commented, you can use the [`openssl` command](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Generating_a_File_Hash) to accomplish this:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 file1
openssl dgst -sha384 file1
openssl dgst -sha512 file1
```